# Can I test whether a variable has been allocated using new or malloc?

Tags: c++, malloc, heap-memory, new-operator

Is there a way to know whether the memory of a pointer variable has been allocated using `new` or `malloc`?

```
int* a = new int;
int* b = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof *b));

//Maybe using a function?
allocatedwithnew(a); //Returns true
allocatedwithmalloc(b); //Return true
```

Comment: `A obj3 = malloc(sizeof(int));` won't compile.  So may be pick a better example.  Creating objects (not just storage) with malloc is UB as the constructor(s) will not be called.

Comment: No, there isn't. The best solution to this problem is to always use `new`, making it disappear as if by magic.

Comment: Clear case of XY problem. VTC.

Comment: @molbdnilo 's solution is the best. Go to `src/` dir, replace `malloc` with `new` and start fixing compiler errors.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try with counters?

As far as I understand your code looks like this:

```
if(ConditionA) {
  A obj = new A;
} else {
  A obj = malloc(sizeof(int));
}
```

You could do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

struct A{
  int ab;
  bool createdByNew;
};

int main()
{
    int CountNewAllocations=0;
    int CountMallocAllocations=0;
    bool Condition=true; // this will be set to appropriate value

    A *obj = NULL;

    if(Condition) {
      obj = new A;
      obj->createdByNew=true;
      CountNewAllocations++;
    } else {
      obj = (A*) malloc(sizeof(A));
      obj->createdByNew=false;
      CountMallocAllocations++;
    }

    // ... use the object

    if(obj!=NULL) {
      if(obj->createdByNew) {
        delete obj;
        CountNewAllocations--;
      } else {
        free(obj);
        CountMallocAllocations--;
      }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will not compile. It would also leak if it did.

Comment: Terrible idea. Asusming compilation errors are fixed, how would the pointer be freed?

Comment: I changed the code. This is my idea for solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You could use a define which replaces new with NEW, and then set the define to

```
static int newCounter = 0;
#define NEW(A) ++newCounter; new A

static int mallocCounter = 0;
#define MALLOC(A) ++malloCounter; malloc A
```

Comment: Terrible suggestion.

Comment: Could you tell me why it's a bad suggestion? A function won't solve it as neatly as this would

Comment: It's a bad idea because using a macro whose name is the same as a keyword produces undefined behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA - "You could use a define which replaces new..."

Comment: @PeteBecker, Oh yes, I only focused on code. However,  I am unfamiliar with section of the standard which specifies undefined behavior for collisions between macro and keyword name - can you please provide a reference?

Comment: The code is an example, I did not know about the collision between them, since technically they do not share a name (all caps vs all lower)

Comment: @JoeyvanGangelen - `NEW` and `new` are, as you say, two different things. I may have read too much into "You could use a define which replaces new ...", which would produce undefined behavior. If you are suggesting **replacing** every occurrence of `new` with `NEW` that's a different matter.

Comment: That's exactly what I ment Pete ^^
Could you remove your -1 if you believe it's a valid answer? Trying to reach 20 reputation for chat :)